# Trying to run testcafe with jenkins manually but getting error

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

hello I followed everything in this article https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/jenkins.html

When I am running it shows this error:

ERROR ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
at Object. (E:\jenkins\builds\workspace\Automation\node_modules\queue-microtask\index.js:5:25)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
at Module._compile (E:\jenkins\builds\workspace\Automation\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:547:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object. (E:\jenkins\builds\workspace\Automation\node_modules\run-parallel\index.js:4:24)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
at Module._compile (E:\jenkins\builds\workspace\Automation\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:547:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.

What am i doing wrong ? how can i resolve this GlobalThis error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on similar issues, I assume you need to update your Node.js version:

https://github.com/datproject/dat-store/issues/49